# The population $P$ of a bacteria with respect to time $t$ can be modeled by the equation: $P=500(4+\frac{5t}{70+t^2})$

Tags: calculus, derivatives, solution-verification

Test 2 Review question #7

The population $P$ of a bacteria with respect to time $t$ can be modeled by the equation:

$P=500(4+\frac{5t}{70+t^2})$

Caluclate the rate of change of the population with respect to time when $t=2$

Verify the solution:

$Solution$:

So, we need to calculate $\frac{dP}{dt}$ and then plug in $t=2$.

$\frac{d}{dt}P=\frac{d}{dt}(500(4+\frac{5t}{70+t^2}))$

$\frac{dP}{dt}=500(\frac{d}{dt}4+\frac{d}{dt}\frac{5t}{70+t^2})$

$\frac{dP}{dt}=500(0+\frac{d}{dt}\frac{5t}{70+t^2})$

$\frac{dP}{dt}=500(\frac{d}{dt}\frac{5t}{70+t^2})$

We are going to have to use the quotient to compute $\frac{d}{dt}\frac{5t}{70+t^2}$

$\frac{dP}{dt}=500(\frac{(70+t^2)(\frac{d}{dt}5t)-(5t)(\frac{d}{dt}(70+t^2))}{(70+t^2)^2})$

$\frac{dP}{dt}=500(\frac{(70+t^2)(5)-(5t)(2t)}{(70+t^2)^2})$

$\frac{dP}{dt}=500(\frac{(350+5t^2)-10t^2}{(70+t^2)^2}$

$\frac{dP}{dt}=500(\frac{(350-5t^2}{(70+t^2)^2})$

Cool, now we just have to plug in $t=2$

$\frac{dP}{dt}=500(\frac{(350-5(2)^2}{(70+2^2)^2})$

$\frac{dP}{dt}=500(\frac{(350-5(4)}{(70+4)^2})$

$\frac{dP}{dt}=500(\frac{(330}{(74)^2})$

$\frac{dP}{dt}=500(\frac{(330}{5476}) \cong 30.13$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing much for me to say: your answer is quite correct by my checking!

Comment: @Leucippus How is this not an answer?

Comment: @Leucippus What makes you say that? The question is to verify the provided solution. The consensus is that is is correct. What else do you expect an answer to say?

Answer (score 0):

Your answer is correct, and in the spirit of teaching a man to fish, here's how you can check yourself the next time: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=d%2Fdt%28500%284%2B5t%2F%2870%2Bt%5E2%29%29%29+when+t%3D2

Comment: I'm posting these solutions here so my students can see them, thanks though.